# Get buyers name and email in digital goods paypal express checkout process

Tags: php, paypal

```
digital goods Paypal express checkout Response
```

> 'TOKEN' =>  'EC-9L3243470D133010L' 
>             'SUCCESSPAGEREDIRECTREQUESTED' =>  'false'
>             'TIMESTAMP' =>  '2013-07-05T17:26:59Z'
>             'CORRELATIONID' => '59c810095e7aa'
>             'ACK' =>  'Success'
>             'VERSION' => '84' 
>             'BUILD' =>  '6680107' 
>             'INSURANCEOPTIONSELECTED' =>  'false'
>             'SHIPPINGOPTIONISDEFAULT' => 'false'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID' =>'7EK01421BP835482W'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONTYPE' => 'cart'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTTYPE' => 'instant'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_ORDERTIME' => '2013-07-05T17:26:58Z'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_AMT' => '11.00'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_FEEAMT' => '0.60'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_TAXAMT' =>  '0.00'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_PAYMENTSTATUS' =>  'Completed'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_PENDINGREASON' =>'None'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_REASONCODE' =>  'None'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITY' => 'Ineligible'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_PROTECTIONELIGIBILITYTYPE' => 'None'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_SECUREMERCHANTACCOUNTID' =>  'PXRAD757S9D26'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_ERRORCODE' => string '0'
>             'PAYMENTINFO_0_ACK' => 'Success'

```
       this response i am getting when implementing digital goods paypal express checkout process but no where i am getting buyers information.
Please help me out to get the buyers information !! thanks in advance...
```

Comment: This information isn't provided by `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`. Try calling [GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) instead.